# As I create a function that once activated, responds to a text message

Tags: arduino

I'm practicing simple functions and now I want them to respond to the interaction through text messages, but I don't know what the command is or how that command would work

What would be the command with which the program asks if you want to turn on the light (LED incorporated in Arduino board / genuine One), if you answer N or NO,
turn off the LED; If yes or yes, does the LED turn on?

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.println(" Do you want the light to come on? ");
  Serial.println(" answer Y or yes to turn it on and N or no to turn it 
  off");
}
```

Let the program ask if you "want to turn on the light?" and after that the plate responds:
If you answer NO or NO, turn off the LED;
If yes or yes, turn on the LED

Comment: You can use `Serial.read()` to get info from the laptop back to the Arduino board through the serial cable. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Arduino manual. Especially

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

There are various functions to read received data from the serial interface's input buffer.

There are countless tutorials available online, covering any aspect of serial communication.

Usually you're constantly checking if there is any data available. If so, read and interpet it.